# JSON to model a class using Django

Tags: python, django, json, object

I'm trying to get a JSON object like:

```
{
    "username": "clelio",
    "name": "Clelio de Paula",
}
```

and transform it in:

```
  class User(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     username = models.CharField(max_length=20)

     def jsonToClass(s):

       aux = json.dumps(s, self)

       self.name = aux['name']
       self.id = aux['id']
```

So I tried to use the `simplejson` and one method called `jsonToClass()`:

```
  >>> import simplejson as json
  >>> u1 = User()
  >>> u1.jsonToClass(face)
  >>> u1.save()
```

This doesn't work. What is the easiest method to do what I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want to look at Django's [(de)serialization framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/). Given JSON like:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.user",
    "pk": "89900",
    "fields": {
      "name": "Clelio de Paula"
    }
  }
]
```

you can save it like this:

```
from django.core import serializers
for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
    deserialized_object.save()
```

Note that I believe you have to use the Django serialization format to use this method, so you might have to adjust your JSON accordingly.

Comment: Well, you could use the `json` module to wrap the response in the outer array and object required by the serialization module. But that might be overkill.

Comment: Thanks @nrabinowitz, I'm going to read the deserialization framework, but I need to get this json objects by http request, and don't has a standard

because sometimes I'm getting data using graph.facebook.com and another youtube api.

Comment: I should also point out that in your original code, json.dumps() should be json.loads(s) - that's probably why the original code didn't work.

Comment: @nrabinowitz The type of `deserialized_object` is `DeserializedObject`. How can I convert that into a django model class type. (Assume that the JSON object I want to deserialize is returned by serializing a model object)

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that

```
{
    "username": "clelio",
    "name": "Clelio de Paula",
 }
```

is a dict() object.

So, this is easiest than I thought.

What I need to solve is just

```
def jsonToClass(self, aux):

    self.name = aux['name']
    self.username = aux['username']
```

that's it.

Comment: somewhat dangerous but maybe ok (sometimes) probably should do some checks and whatnot `self.__dict__.update(aux)`

Comment: How is this dangerous? Is it because it might get duplicate keys (and override distinct values) if data isn't checked?

Comment: Because you can have fields on your model that are Python properties, and guarded by complex setters. Otherwise, there is no type-checking or validation at all - but if you trust your data , that might work

Answer (score 0):

This is simply achieved as follows:

```
data = {
   "username": "stackExchange",
   "name": "stack overflow"
}

for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
    do_something_with(obj)
```

[Check out django docs for details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/)

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'` is the error I get with Django 2.2.11 with Python 3.7.2