# How to deserialize a django model object?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am fairly new to python and transitioning from Java, so I'll use the Java terminologies as I need to know the equivalent python version of it.

So I have a Django model as described below:

```
class Order(models.Model) :
    order_id = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
```

Also I have a **kafka broker** to process these orders. To push these into a kafka queue, I am transforming them into JSON objects as depicted below:

```
from django.core import serializers

serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [order])
print("Pushing to kafka topic ", "some_topic")
print(serialized_obj)
send_message("some_topic", serialized_obj)
```

Now I need this JSON object to be converted back to Django model object, in **Java** we have something called as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) which could have done the same for me, but I am not sure how to do this in Python3.

I tried the below code snippet, it returned me an object of type `<generator object Deserializer at 0x7fe000323bf8>`

```
# consumer.py
try:
  print(json.loads(msg.value()))
  print("---------------------------------")
  obj = serializers.deserialize("json", msg.value())
  print(obj)
  except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

How can I achieve this in Python3?

Comment: May be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719864/json-to-model-a-class-using-django

Comment: It does not answer this statement, How can I convert that into a django model class type?

Answer (score 3):

First to serialize the object do this:

```
from django.core import serializers

d = serializers.serialize('json', Order.objects.all()) # serialize all the objects in Order model
```

To deserialize the object from it

```
for obj in serializers.deserialize('json', d):
    print(obj.object) ## return the django model class object
```

`serializers.deserialize()` gives an Deserializedobject

To get more details refer [Django object deserialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data)

Comment: It does not answer this statement, How can I convert that into a django model class type?

Comment: Yes it does.  If the object that was serialized is a Django Model object (as it is in OP's post), then deserializing and accessing the .object property will give you a Django Model type object.