# Django Design: Store Extracted File Contents Automatically to DB

Tags: python, django

In my application, I have a scraper that kicks off every morning, generates the daily Islamic prayer times and saves them in a text file. I need to extract the contents from this file and save them to a db. I would like to have Django/Python automatically do this for me, check the file if it exists and slurps up the contents.

The contents in the text file looks something like this:

`{"sunrise": "6:30AM", "noon": "12PM", "afternoon" : "5:30PM"}`

How do I go about writing the Model class? Should I go with a variable for each entry, meaning:

`pSunrise, tSunrise, pNoon, tNoon...etc`

(p = prayer, t = time)

Or does it get stored differently? Secondly, how do I initiate Django to automate this for me? This has been bugging me for quite a while and I greatly appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: Break it down into smaller pieces. Your first problem is getting the data from the text files. Are you aware of JSON?

Comment: The file format does not matter. However, how would you do it in JSON?

Comment: just a thought: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719864/json-to-model-a-class-using-django

Comment: also https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Thank you Paul for the django-cron; I will definitely read this. I never used serialization, so I am a bit confused (please forgive me for my stupid questions). 

1. Would the serialized code be in the Model or View section?
2. Would I need to change the output of the JSON file for serialization; meaning does it need to look more like this:

```[
  {
    "model": "myapp.user",
    "pk": "89900",
    "fields": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
]```

Or can I just leave the output the way it is as shown in my original question?

Thank you again!

Comment: you should create the files using json.dumps and load it in via json.loads. You should not fiddle manually as there are many edge cases

Comment: as to your other questions, suggest you do a few django tutorials.